# Custom renders of nuGet Package conflict in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm making app with using Xamarin.forms. (PCL)

I just noticed serious problem of using custom renderer.
I came from this thread.
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/54317/new-xamarin-forms-guide-custom-renderers/p2

This thread says, and I experienced that Only ONE renderer class works at the same time.
It means that if two different package use same renderer, one of them will not work. (It follows class hierarchy. so subclassed class will work and other stop working)

Package just added might break original package or mine, and real problem is that developer might not notice at that time.

Why is that how it works?
Or, am I not correct or did mistake?

- example

If you already made your custom renderer for ContentPage and installed package which has custom renderer for ContentPage or Page. In my case, KeyboardOverlap.Forms.Plugin does. And Both Renderer class overrided OnApearing(). When you run your app. Only one renderer's OnApearing will be fired.

Of course I can hand merge that. But what if both of them are nuGet Package and can not modify them. (Of course I can use Github's but that cause another problem)

Comment: can you give an example? I'm not sure I fully follow. I write some pretty complicated apps with forms and have never run into an issue whereby a renderer doesn't work.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell If you already made your custom renderer for ContentPage and installed package which has custom renderer for ContentPage or Page. In my case, KeyboardOverlap.Forms.Plugin does. And Both Renderer class overrided OnApearing(). When you run your app. Only one renderer's OnApearing will be fired.

Comment: don't each of the custom renderers have a unique name? The only way this fails is if you override the default... never do that, instead inherit from the default and make sure to call `base` when you override. If a nuget pkg is broken because they're overriding the default, tell them to fix it.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell Thank Chase, I wrote comment on your answer. Could you please answer that question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each custom renderer should have a unique name. The only way you'll get collisions is if your renderer is overriding the base class... NEVER DO THAT, but instead you should inherit from the default and make sure to call `base` when you override.

If a nuget package is broken because they're overriding the default, you have to tell them to fix it.

In the code you're referring to, the author is overriding `Page` instead of making his own `KeyboardOverlapPage`

[This line is causing you pain!](https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/blob/40f892fc868b540fd02cef34c2bd216fa166a6a1/KeyboardOverlap/KeyboardOverlap/KeyboardOverlap.Forms.Plugin.iOSUnified/KeyboardOverlapRenderer.cs#L10)

Instead it should be

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(KeyboardOverlapPage), typeof(KeyboardOverlapRenderer))]
```

And then have a class in the PCL

```
public class KeyboardOverlapPage : Xamarin.Forms.Page {}
```

In other words, the author has a poorly implemented package and should fix it. Once fixed, you can use a  wherever you want that functionality in place of a page.

If there is no custom renderer on a specific platform, it will automagically fall back to the default behaviour.

Comment: I've [added an issue](https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/issues/101) to the specific repo you're referring to.

Comment: Hi Chase. Thanks for your generous answer. But I already know avoiding to override default class is the way. But That still means only one renderer can work at a time right? Only was to use both function of renderer is HAND MERGE? I really want to know. If so, isn't it little bit annoying?

Comment: Thanks again for adding an issue.

Comment: The reason why I ask this is, even if KeyboardOverlap creator change their package as you said, It still could break my own custom renderer for XXXContentPage. I have to choose one of them unless I have to HAND MERGE. But there is no chance to merge them when add a nuGet.

Comment: I solved it. It's possible that I subclass my renderer from new plugins renderer as well. Then your answer is absolutely correct. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. He should fix his plugin as you said.

Comment: So if you needed his code in your app, but also wanted to extend it further, you'd simply inherit from his `KeyboardOverlapPage`, and add your functionality.

Comment: And I should subclass his custom renderer class. That's what I found.